# Backbone.js source code - eventsApi

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The following is a snippet from the [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) annotated source code:

```
var eventsApi = function(iteratee, events, name, callback, opts) {
  var i = 0, names;
  if (name && typeof name === 'object') {

    if (callback !== void 0 && 'context' in opts && opts.context === void 0) opts.context = callback;
    for (names = _.key(names); i < names.length; i++) {
      events = eventsApi(iteratee, events, names[i], name[names[i]], opts);
    }
  } else if (name && eventSplitter.test(name)) {
    for (names = name.split(eventSplitter); i < names.length; i++) {
      events = iteratee(events, names[i], callback, opts);
    }
  } else {
    events = iteratee(events, name, callback, opts);
  }
  return events;
};
```

The `eventsApi` function checks for events as objects, in order to handle jQuery-style event maps.

But why does it call `eventsApi` recursively as it iterates through all the events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iteratee in the above is the following:

```
var onApi = function(events, name, callback, options) {
  if (callback) {
    var handlers = events[name] || (events[name] = []);
    var context = options.context, ctx = options.ctx, listening = options.listening;
     if (listening) listening.count++;
    handlers.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || ctx, listening: listening});
  }
    return events;
};
```

it registers an event for single attribute (`name`).

`eventsApi` checks if the second parameter is an object, in that case it calls itself to register events for all the properties of the object, for example the `attributes` object of a model. This is a common use of recursion.